# Unable to install firebase in react using npm install firebase / yarn add firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

iam trying to install firebase depedencies and it still stuck even after 30 minutes

[i've been stuck like 30 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py3m0.png)

can anyone help me?

Comment: You can stop the terminal and try again.

Comment: i already tried that more than 3 times

Comment: Is any error you got on console?

Comment: nothing sir, its only idealTree:firebase-test: sill idealTree buildDeos, stuck

Comment: my connection is not that bad, i tried npm install its still work

Comment: You can follow my answer I think your npm module is currepted

Comment: when i tried to install other depedencies it still work fine, but when i tried npm install firebase its stuck

Comment: You can try to install globally > npm i -g firebase

Comment: still doesn't work sir

Comment: One more thing you can try like remove package.lock.json and delete nodemodules folder and again install npm.

Answer (score 0):

1. you just need firebase on client side
   `npm i firebase`
2. Install globally or locally as devDependency firebase-cli to deploy, connect, login to your firebase-project

`npm i -g firebase-tools`
or
`npm i -d firebase-tools`

3. if you use any cloud-function

`npm i firebase-admin firebase-functions`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like npm cache was corrupted ,but as npm cache clean --force did not work,deleting _cacache directory in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache solved my problem.

Then npm install worked just fine.